# Firestore console - document size limit

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am wondering what is the maximum size of the document that is stored on Firestore? I have a sample json that I am trying to store in Firestore as document, however when I am trying to read it from console, my web browser freezes. There is no problem when reading it from query.
Sample of the document is pasted below:

```
'0':    249999,
'5':    249998,
'10':   249997,
'15':   249996,
'20':   249995,
'25':   249994,
```

The rest of the document content can be found [here](https://pastebin.com/QeCpq62R).

Any idea why the console may freeze?

Comment: Answer below. But this seems like a [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). If you're having problems reading a document, share the [minimum code that allows us to reproduce that problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). I.e. a single snippet of code that allows us to write a document that then subsequently can't be read.

Answer (score 2):

The maximum size of a document is 1MB. See the [Firestore documentation on quota and limits](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quotas#collections_documents_and_fields).

> Maximum size for a document:  1 MiB (1,048,576 bytes)

Comment: Frank, the size of the document doesn't exceed 500,000 bytes. I will post code snippet for that in a while.

Comment: That's what I expected already. But since you asked "what is the maximum size of the document that is stored on Firestore?", that is what I answered. For better help on why your code doesn't work, we'll need an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

There is a cool library that you can use to determine the sizes of your documents and more information about it.

Check it out: https://github.com/alexmamo/FirestoreDocument-Android/tree/master/firestore-document

This library will tell you your document sizes and you can check if a document is less than the current quota of 1Mbit

### Edit

Here you can see how to get the document size with this library, is pretty easy, first you build up a reference to the document you want to get size for, then just use `.getSize()` on that `DocumentReference` or `QueryDocumentSnapshot`

```
 myTaskIdRef.get().addOnCompleteListener(task -> {
            if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                DocumentSnapshot document = task.getResult();
                if (document.exists()) {
                    int documentSize = firestoreDocument.getSize(document);
                    String textToDisplay = "Size: " + documentSize + " bytes";
                    docSizeTextView.setText(textToDisplay);
                }
            }
        });
```

Alternatively this library has a method that returns a boolean value if the document itself is less than 1Mbit

```
  /**
     * @param document The document that we want to know if it's less than 1 Mebibyte
     * @return True if the document is less than 1,048,576 bytes else false.
     */
    public boolean isDocumentSizeLessThanOneMebibyte(DocumentSnapshot document) {
        return getSize(document) < ONE_MEBIBYTE;
    }
```

So we can do from the code above

```
if(isDocumentSizeLessThanOneMebibyte(document)) { 
...
}
```

Each time you do a .getSize() it will check if the document is not nearly hitting the quota, so the library warns you about the current size if it's too high.